# Are the terms "Aircraft Version" and "Aircraft Variant" synonyms?

Tags: terminology, aircraft-naming

Related to the answer of the following question:

[How are evolution and variants of aircraft considered by certification authorities?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/how-are-evolution-and-variants-of-aircraft-considered-by-certification-authoriti)

Are the terms "Aircraft Version" and "Aircraft Variant" synonyms? The answer uses the term "Aircraft Variant" but I have also come across "Aircraft Version" elsewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are evolution and variants of aircraft considered by certification authorities?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/how-are-evolution-and-variants-of-aircraft-considered-by-certification-authoriti)

Comment: I meant to leave a comment earlier. My answer w.r.t. 'version' was not correct after further examination. Note that the linked post explains that *versions* "can vary between authorities," followed by an example.